# How to get n days/months/year date from or before today's date in snowflake?

Tags: cloud, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a requirement wherein I want to get the date 'n' number of days/ months/ year from or before today to basically filter the results of the query in snowflake.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the date 'n' number of days/month/year from the current date as follows:

- Date 5 year from today

`Select dateadd(year, 5, current_date());`

- Date 5 year ago from today

`Select dateadd(year, -5, current_date());`

- Date 2 months from today

`Select dateadd(month, 2, current_date());`

- Date 2 months ago from today

`Select dateadd(month, -2, current_date());`

- Date 2 days from today

`Select dateadd(day, 2, current_date());`

- Date 2 days ago from today

`Select dateadd(day, -2, current_date());`

**Snowflake official documentation**

[DATEADD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd.html)

[Supported Date and Time Parts](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-date-time.html#label-supported-date-time-parts)

Answer (score 1):

An [INTERVAL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#interval-constants) arthimetic could be used:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL '5 year';
SELECT CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL '5 year';
SELECT CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL '2 months';
SELECT CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL '2 months';
```

It also allows to combine multiple intevals:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL '1 year, 3 quarters, 4 months, 5 weeks, 6 days';
```